# How do I force a 16x16 icon size for toolbar icons in GTK 3?

Tags: gnome, customization, gtk3

Is there a way to force 16x16 icon size for toolbar icons in GTK3? In GTK2 it was possible by editing `~/.gtkrc-2.0`. I just do not know how to do this in GTK3.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this by creating/modifying `~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini`:

```
[Settings]
gtk-icon-sizes = panel-menu=16,16:panel=16,16:gtk-menu=16,16:gtk-large-toolbar=16,16:gtk-small-toolbar=16,16:gtk-button=16,16
```

However, your theme may override this in its theme file.